# total sum of y-axis values for several curves plotted with different axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 9 curves which I plot in Python all on the same figure, the x-axis is individual for each curve and I want to obtain the sum of all these curves to have a total final curve.

[image]

This is what I have where the x-axis is (Nt,9) array and I perform an iteration to plot on the same figure the curves with individual x-axis of size (Nt). As I explained I obtain this by performing an iteration, and my question is how can I perform the sum of the above shape to obtain the total shape; like an envelope of the curves, while I have individual x-axis between the plots, is there a direct way to do this?

Comment: can you provide the data/code that you currently have (a minimal dataset it fine as long as it reproduces your issue)?

Comment: Since your array of curves is regular, and you ask about an envelope function (that is, not the combined surface under the curves), you should be able to simply sum along the correct axis. E.g., plotting `data.sum(axis=1)` might work.

Comment: You say the x-axis is individual for each curve. But you also show that each set of x-values is of size Nt, which suggest the x-values are actually all the same, and the *y* values are all different. Could you please explain, possibly with a small example / part of your data?